# MySQL module for Python 3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

MySQLdb as I understand doesn't support Python 3. I've heard about PyMySQL as a replacement for this module. But how does it work in production environment?

Is there a big difference in speed between these two? I asking because I will be managing a very active webapp that needs to create entries in the database very often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyMySQL is a pure-python database connector for MySQL, and can be used as a drop-in replacement using the `install_as_MySQLdb()` function. As a pure-python implementation, it will have some more overhead than a connector that uses C code, but it is compatible with other versions of Python, such as Jython and PyPy.

At the time of writing, Django recommends to use the mysqlclient package on Python 3. This fork of MySQLdb is partially written in C for performance, and is compatible with Python 3.3+. You can install it using `pip install mysqlclient`. As a fork, it uses the same module name, so you only have to install it and Django will use it in its MySQL database engine.